# I want to extract a link from text and style it from API respone

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

This is my API response.
Now I want to extract zoom Link, make it clickable and also style it differently.
It is not in a separate html tag so I find it confusing to achieve it.
<1>Hey ladies and gentelmen</1>\r\n\r\n

info-</>\r\n\r\n

Date: 8909-78-09

\r\n\r\n

time: Evening

\r\n\r\n

Platform: (Zoom)

\r\n\r\n

To participate: https://us06web.zoom.us/j/2670566985?pwd=UTRYVHN5YWl0aU5rclBmaXZ0cGJ6QT0

Currently I am only rendering the response with flutter_html package.

Answer (score 1):

You can try LinkfyText() using https://pub.dev/packages/linkfy_text
This Package helps you to linkifies a text containing urls, emails, mentions

```dart
Container(
    child: LinkifyText(
    "This text contains a url: https://flutter.dev",
    linkStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
    onTap: (link) {
        /// do stuff with `link`
        },
    );
)
```

Comment: LinkifyText accepts text but I can not provide text directly to it as it is in html format so it has to go through html parsing first.. right?

Comment: Yup first use HTML() for parsing html text then use LinkfyText()